# Why don't I have to give the function the address of the array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Hi I'm new to C and learning about pointers. I'm writing a simple recursive function to test it where it takes parameters `int *a` and `int size`. In my main method, I send `print_array` the address of the first character of my array using the `&` beforehand.

This doesn't seem to work, I get given an "incompatible pointer types" error at compilation. I understand that I can remove the & and the program works fine. I have a question:

Why can't I pass in the memory address of my_array from main with a &? Shouldn't I be able to just give the function the memory address of first element of array and it can deal with the rest?

Thanks, hope this question wasn't too noob.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


void print_array(int *a, int size){
    if (size>0){
            printf("%d\n", a[0]);
            print_array(a+1, size-1);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int my_array[20];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < 20; i++){
            my_array[i] = rand() % 20;
    }

    /*the contents of the array*/
    printf("The contents of the array\n");
    for (i=0; i < 20; i++){
            printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    }

    printf("The recursive method print\n");

    print_array(&my_array, 20);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can give the function the address of the first element, and let it deal with the rest. You could do that as either:

```
print_array(my_array, 20);
```

...or:

```
print_array(&my_array[0], 20);
```

Unfortunately, while `&my_array` is legal code, it produces a pointer to the entire array, rather than a pointer to the first element of the array. Those have the same address, but different types, which is what's causing the error.

The type of a pointer determines (among other things) how arithmetic on that pointer will work. In your case, `print_array` prints the first int in the array, then adds one to the pointer. Since it's a pointer to int, that addition actually adds the size of an int to the address in the pointer.

If you used a pointer to the entire array, then adding one would instead add the size of the entire array to the address. For example, let's assume 4-byte ints and that my_array has a base address of 1000. In this case, `my_array+1` will yield 1004, so it holds the address of the second int in the array (just as you undoubtedly wanted). By contrast, `&my_array` will take the address of the entire array, with the type "pointer to array of 20 ints". When you add one to it, that will add 1 * the size of the pointed-to type to the address, so you'll get `1080` (i.e., the entire array is 20 * 4 = 80 bytes). This is obviously *not* what you wanted--instead of `x+1` pointing to the second item *in* the array, it now points past the end of the array, and attempting to dereference the pointer will give undefined behavior.

So, just switch to one of the forms above (`my_array` or `&my_array[0]`). As a more general point, realize that the name of an array evaluates as a pointer to the first element of the array under most circumstances--the notable exceptions being when you use the name of the array as a the operand of either the `sizeof` operator or the address-of operator (as you did here). In these two cases, the name of the array still refers to the entire array instead of a pointer to the first element.

Comment: If the first argument of `print_array` was declared as `int (*a)[20]`, then you could pass `&my_array` to it.  But `int *a` is a pointer to an integer, not a pointer to an array of 20 integers.  That's why you have to pass the address of the array's first element, instead of the address of the array itself (even though they have the same numeric value).

Comment: @Wyzard: Yes, if the argument was declared as `int (*a)[20]`, you could pass `&my_array`, but then the `a+1` inside of `print_array` would produce undefined behavior.

Comment: "Unfortunately, while &my_array is legal code, it produces a pointer to the entire array, rather than a pointer to the first element of the array. Those have the same address, but different types, which is what's causing the error."

Could you elaborate on this please? So `&my_array` will give me a pointer to the whole array? How would they be different types of they're both pointing to the same block? thanks

Comment: @magna_nz: I've added more detail about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs a pointer to an `int`, specifically the address of the first (0th) element of the array.

By calling `print_array(&my_array, 20);`, you're trying to pass the address of the entire array, a value of type `int(*)[20]`, which is different than `int*`. It points to the same memory location, but it's of a different type.

To pass the address of the first element, you can write:

```
print_array(&my_array[0], 20);
```

or, equivalently:

```
print_array(my_array, 20);
```

The latter works because, in most but not all contexts, the name of an array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

The relationship between arrays and pointers in C and C++ can be confusing. Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays automatically decay to pointers, the following was extracted from the n1570 draft

> **6.3.2 Other operands**
>
> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
>
> 3. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>      unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>      type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>      to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
>      register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Note that the wording about the `_Alignof` operator is incorrect, and was removed from the final C11 standard. Unlike `sizeof`, `_Alignof` can only be applied to a type, not to an expression. (It's not clear why this is.)

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for the remark, I do not own the `C11` standard. Just the draft.